# Product of $N$ Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus

I am trying to perform diagonalization on an Ising Hamiltonian, with $N$ spins, containing a term of the form
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sigma_i^{x} = \sum_ {i=1}^{N} 1_1 \otimes \cdots 1_{i-1} \otimes \sigma_i^{x} \otimes 1_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes 1_{N},   \qquad (*)
\end{equation}
where 
$
\sigma_i^{x} = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

Apart from $(*)$, the Hamiltonian contains additional operators.
The size of this Hamiltonian matrix is $2^{N}$, so finding its eigenvalues is computationally expensive even for small $N$. This matrix is very sparse, so I was wondering if there is an efficient way of knowing exactly which values of $(*)$ are non-zero, without computing explicitly the tensor product.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression seems to have a state on the LHS and an operator on the RHS, so it's a bit confusing.  I'll assume that what you want are the eigenvectors of the RHS operator. To simplify I will replace the $\sigma_x$ by $\sigma_z$, then the state
$$
\vert m_1\rangle\otimes \vert m_2\rangle \otimes \ldots \otimes  \vert m_N\rangle
$$
where $m_i =\pm 1/2$ and $\sigma_z\vert m\rangle=m\vert m\rangle$  is  an eigenstate of your RHS operator $(\sigma_z)_{\rm tot}$  with eigenvalue 
$$
m_{\rm tot}= m_1+m_2+\ldots+m_N.
$$
How to  change back to $\sigma_x$ should  now be clear!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mike. I may have not been clear enough in the question. I am not trying to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the RHS operator, but of the complete Hamiltonian, which contains additional terms. Also, $(\sigma_z)_{tot}$ is diagonal, which I think oversimplifies the problem.

Comment: If you're looking for *all* the exact eigenvalues and eigenvectors you're SOL.

Comment: I'm only trying to find some of them, not all.

Comment: For numerical eigenvalues of sparse matrices, the Lanczos algorithm is a good technique.